# Validation rule not working. Pls suggest any idea

Tags: validation-rule

i have 2 objects,Case(Parent) and Issue (Child). Having master detail relationship..

Issues__c is a roll up summary field that counts the no. of records in issue object.

Here is the rule:

```
IF
(
AND(RecordType.DeveloperName == "Standard_Case",
Issues__c=0,
OR(ISCHANGED(Status),ISNEW()),
OR(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"),ISPICKVAL(Status, "Duplicate"))
),
true,
false)
```

Please suggest any idea!

Comment: Can you please add little bit description about how your validation rule should work?

Comment: This validation rule should fire an error when a user tries to close a Case record (standard case recordtype) that do not have any issues (child record) associated. same time should not allow the user to update the status as weel, if there are no child records associated.

Comment: try with this `IF
(
 AND(RecordType.DeveloperName == "Standard_Case",
 Issues__c=0,
 ISCHANGED(Status),
 OR(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"),ISPICKVAL(Status, "Duplicate"))
),
true,
false)`

Comment: Could you please let me know, what's problem with this? is there any problem with the IF condition?? could you please guide me here

Comment: venky ... No there is no problem just you can reduce the code little bit `AND(RecordType.DeveloperName == "Standard_Case", Issues__c=0, ISCHANGED(Status), OR(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"), ISPICKVAL(Status, "Duplicate")) )`

Comment: yeah, that's fine..it is working in sandbox...but user is complaining that he's not getting any error..both sandbox and PROD have the same above logic..do u have any idea, any root cause for this to happen???

Comment: so based on above logic error will be occur when your recordType is Standard_Case and Issues__c is zero and status changed and status is Closed or Duplicate... This is how above validation rule will work.. is there anything I am missing

Comment: you understanding is absolutely correct!!

Comment: venky then it should work... fine.. please give answer to your question and accept that.. let me know if you need any help here thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND(
    RecordType.DeveloperName == "Standard_Case",
    Issues__c=0,
    ISCHANGED(Status),
    OR(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"), ISPICKVAL(Status, "Duplicate"))
)
```